# Manejo de javaScrip en phoenix elixir

Tags: javascript, framework, elixir

basicamente lo que me esta ocurriendo es que estoy manejando un javascript desde un hook en mi aplicacion de phoenix lo que hace este javascript es habilitar el microfono para grabar y enviar datos a un channel pero algo que me esta ocurriendo es que cuando quiero detener la grabacion y apagar el microfono recibo el siguiente mensaje :

```
Uncaught DOMException: AudioNode.disconnect: Trying to disconnect from a node we're not connected to
```

el cual se ocasiona en la siguiente funcion

```
AudioRecorder.stopRecording = function() {
        streamStreaming = false;
      
        let track = globalStream.getTracks()[0];
        track.stop();
      
        input.disconnect(processor); (y para ser mas específicos en esta linea de codigo)
        processor.disconnect(context.destination);
        context.close().then(function () {
          input = null;
          processor = null;
          context = null;
          AudioContext = null;
          
        });
      } // closes function stopRecording(
```

lo que no estoy entendiendo es que esta causando este error en particular